# iPhone: Possible to change the color of just the prompt of the UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationbar

I'm wondering if I can change the background color of just the prompt of the UINavigationBar (e.g. to red, while the rest of the navigation bar stays black), so I can use the prompt property of the UINavigationItem to display status / error messages as a one-liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. But you can set the prompt to an empty string, and place a red-colored label on top of it.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but since the introduction of `appearance` there is a much easier way to setting prompt color (and other properties) than adding a subview.

in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` put

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor theColorYouWantYourPromptToBe], UITextAttributeTextColor, otherVariables, nil]];
```

Comment: Thanks, great for iOS5. You may need to customize also the Shadow, so here is the full line of code : `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.3f], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil]];`

Comment: This does indeed change the Color of the Prompt, but it also changes the color of the Title. Is there a way to just change the prompt color?

Comment: If there's an internal variable for the prompt text color alone I have not found it. At that point it would be quicker (and safer) to use a custom subclass.