# iOS 13 Navigation Bar Prompt is Always Black

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios13

I have read the other posts about the `UINavigationBar`'s `Prompt` not following the color values of the actual `Title`. Most of the posts are from the iOS 11 era, and the solutions no longer work on iOS 13.

[image: UINavigationBar Prompt]

These are examples of previous posts that no longer have working solutions:

- [Can't change UINavigationBar prompt color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266310/cant-change-uinavigationbar-prompt-color)
- [Change font of prompt in UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49455068/change-font-of-prompt-in-uinavigationcontroller)
- [iPhone: Possible to change the color of just the prompt of the UINavigationBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027573/iphone-possible-to-change-the-color-of-just-the-prompt-of-the-uinavigationbar)

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Check that the device is not running in Dark Mode.
2. Verify that the background-color was not modified anywhere in the code.
3. Make sure that the style is set to default like in the screenshot below:

[image]